# Linux/glibc queries localhost for DNS even if no resolver is configured

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, glibc

Basically, with an empty resolv.conf (and no weird stuff configured like resolvconf, nscd...nothing at all, just a plain squeeze install), I see DNS queries to 127.0.0.1 port 53 when trying to resolve a name. Has that always been that way?

/etc/nsswitch.conf has the typical "hosts: files dns" line.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's libc's default/ fallback behaviour.

Tried to reconstruct what you did. This stops, if you change your nsswitch.conf-entry to:

`hosts: files`

See also this hint:
http://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2009-02/msg00028.html

See 'man 5 resolv.conf':

```
   If this file doesn't exist the only name server to be queried will be  on  the
   local  machine; the domain name is determined from the hostname and the domain
   search path is constructed from the domain name.
```